# Can atmospheric pressure literally push electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, waves, atmospheric-science, signal-processing

I work for an IT company and some time ago we had an issue with our wireless internet. We are 5 miles away from the ISP's antenna. Our Sys Admin expressed the view that the electromagnetic waves are being literally pushed to the ground because of high atmospheric pressure and the signal gets disrupted by EM waves being scattered by objects on the ground.

Is this a plausible explanation? I would be interested in the limiting conditions (what must be happening for this to occur?).

Comment: Are these point-to-point microwave links?  What band?

Comment: I think it is changes in the ionosphere that affect radio waves and would affect electromagnetic waves too. Storms also affect them because of the electricity of the clouds.

Comment: @BrandonEnright :: I do not have any information about the physical properties of the waves other that they fall into some kind of standart waves used for wireless internet connection. I'm guessing that information about the distance through which they have to travel is significant for your question. 

Let's make the question more general, maybe this will give us hints for the specific case: can atmosperic pressure directly affect EM waves of any kind?

Comment: But why would atmospheric pressure only push down? It would push in all directions and the fluctuations in pressure are very small compared to the absolute pressure.

Comment: @fibonatic :: this is what I was overlooking! The hint that atmosperic preasure acts in all direcctions is a good hint and it sugest the Sys Admin seems to be wrong in his explanation. The second suggestion is also good. Thanks

Comment: In the absence of chemical/ionic changes in air composition, the only way pressure alone could change the path of radiation would be through it's constitutive effect on the dielectric constant of the air; temperature and pressure affect the refractive index of air (such as seen in mirage effects in the desert), and could potentially act as a graded index lens to bend the waves. But you'd have to ask someone more competent than I about the magnitude of this bending; I highly suspect it's negligible, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internet propagates with [radio waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_propagation). Radio waves take advantage of a [wave guide generated by the charged ionosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-ionosphere_waveguide) and the ground  for long distance propagation.

Storm fronts with lightning and charged clouds do interfere with the propagation of a signal.

> Sudden changes in the atmosphere's vertical moisture content and temperature profiles can on random occasions make microwave and UHF & VHF signals propagate hundreds of kilometers up to about 2,000 kilometers (1,300 mi)—and for ducting mode even farther—beyond the normal radio-horizon. The inversion layer is mostly observed over high pressure regions,

which is a change in improving  propagation. I would expect that the inverse, sudden dryness and temperature changes, might act to interfere with the propagation in a negative manner.

Anyway the effect of pressure would be a second order effect on the electromagnetic waves, which can only be directly affected by charge distributions and not by gas pressure.

Comment: Hi Anna, usually the link the questioner describes uses parabolic dishes communicating line-of-sight in the 2.4 GHz band.  The ionosphere has nothing to do with line-of-sight communication.  You're referring to omni-directional radio waves bouncing off of the upper atmosphere (ionosphere).

Comment: @BrandonEnright the questioner is vague on this. On the net I found that the WiFi signals are on the radio wave frequencies and and up to 300 gigaherz are counted as radio frequencies (wikipedia). The only connection with weather other than storms is the ionosphere which is also affected by geomagnetic storms. Have you seen or know of  anything else?